# Android studio - slow loading of Android SDK after upgrade it (windows and macos x)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the last version 1.4 of Android Studio but when I open SDK manager it's a pain wait for the loading, sometimes 5 minutos other times even more... 
This problem becomes after upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4

Sometimes "Internal error message" appears.
Access from terminal to open Android SDK is faster.

**Both computers are i7 and there are not internet issues.**

Anyone knows which is the reason and how to fix it?

- I have already tried re-installing.
- When I open SDK Manager from terminal everything goes faster.

[image]

## EDIT

Using wireshark I figure out this url Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml is an operation timed out

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: so... buy a faster PC... maybe or a SSD.

Comment: Both computers are i7 and there are not internet issues.

Comment: HDD or SSD? I also have a i7 and it tooks 7min with HHD using Windows 7 and 35sec with SSD using Windows 10 same PC using 2 boot OS. (20sec with mid 2015 macbook pro SSD).

Comment: It takes a while to load up on some computers, I had a i7 packed with RAM and a decent HHD and it would creep until I upgraded to SSD (similar to what @MarianoZorrilla is saying). I have noticed it also running slower on Windows machines, but that is also somewhat hardware related.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla SSD and 8GB RAM. I know how memory levels works, it's not a hardware issue. As I say this problem becomes after upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4

Comment: @zgc7009 I think it's not a hardware issue. I said this problem becomes after upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4

Comment: did you try a clean install?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you unplug all USB devices and try to launch it. It was the case for me.